# Accessing local network while using a wireless router

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, internet, wireless-router

I primarily use an Ethernet cable attached to a wireless router to connect to the internet. My router (a Netgear N600) connects to my ISP over PPPoE and is assigned a single public IP address.

Where I live I am provided with a single Ethernet connection which connects to my University's local network as well as the internet.

However, I frequently have to access resources which are only accessible on my University's local area network. Since my router can't access this network, it means disconnecting the wireless router from the internet and plugging the cable into my computer.

Doing this restricts internet access to all of the devices connected to the wireless router — something I'd like to avoid if possible.

When I connect my Ethernet cable to my computer, it connects to the local network and to the internet using two different network interfaces and is assigned different IP addresses for each interface:

[image: Ethernet interface IP address]

[image: PPPoE interface IP address]

I'd like to find some solution in which I can maintain a wireless network while still being able to access both the local area network and the internet, much like my computer does.

What hardware would be required for something like this, assuming such a solution exists?

Comment: Ugh, a university student. So can you get the student access from the university internet, I assume that you are able to use files from the university, which you cannot access through the Ethernet? I mean with WiFi you cannot access and with Ethernet only. Is that correct or an I wrong? Please answer that question so that I could provide you the possible solution.

Comment: I am connected to the internet through an ISP via PPPoE. The ISP is not affiliated with the university. The connection which is provided provides access to both the internal network and the internet. I cannot access the internal network using my own wireless router, but I can when the Ethernet cable is connected to my computer, as my computer is assigned two different IP addresses. I'm wanting to see if a solution exists in which a wireless router can provide the same connectivity which my computer does.